# CSS is not working, W3.CSS overwriting?

Tags: html, css

I copied a W3.CSS template and I am going to use it as a base to build my webpage. I am trying to add some custom CSS to change the text, but for some reason it doesn't work? I am importing the custom CSS file after the W3.CSS so it will overwrite the W3.CSS but for some reason it sticks with the W3.CSS...
Here are my files and code:
style.css (custom css):

```
h1 {
    font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
    color:red;
}
.heading {
    font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
    color:red;
}
```

And index.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3-theme-black.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<style>
html,body,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif}
</style>
```

Then later in index.html:

```
<div class="w3-row w3-padding-64">
    <div class="w3-twothird w3-container">
      <h1 class="w3-text-teal heading">Heading</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Lorem ipsum
        dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The  heading is blue but I want it red. My CSS is not working for some reason... I tried my css on a blank html template and it worked so W3 is doing something but I don't know why.

Comment: First thing to check. If you put color: red !important; - Does it turn red then?

Comment: Open up your browser's inspector and take a look at how it's processing the CSS.

Comment: @ceejayoz What is browser inspector? Sorry I'm kind of new to html

Comment: @mayersdesign Yes it does hmm

Comment: @FerragusBoulé It's the most important tool you'll ever work with when working on HTML/CSS/JS. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/f12-devtools-guide

Comment: Oh inspect element? I haven't really used it but I got an answer and it worked. thanks for the info :) I will use that next time to find out issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work, so I checked the W3 CSS and it has an !important tag on w3-text-teal, which means it will overwrite no matter what, unless you also include an !important tag in your css. So what you can do is:
style.css:

```
h1 {
    font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
    color:red;
}
.heading {
    font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
    color:red !important;
}
```

You should never use !important unless you really have to. But since W3.css uses it a lot apparently then you have to with your current setup. You can also remove the `w3-text-teal` class from your  tag and it will work too, without having to add an !important tag. I recommend doing this because then you don't have to use the !important tag.

```
<h1 class="heading">Heading</h1>
```

instead of:

```
<h1 class="w3-text-teal heading">Heading</h1>
```

And your css remains the same:

```
h1 {
    font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
    color:red;
}
.heading {
    font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
    color:red;
}
```

Comment: !important worked, and also removing w3-text-teal. So I stay with removing w3-text-teal and not having !important right?

Comment: @FerragusBoulé Yes do not add any !important tags and stay with just removing w3-text-teal. Do not use !important unless you really have to.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove w3-text-teal.

Using two different classes for changing the text color doesn't make sense. Stick to your own class in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is months late but the other factor you should consider when overriding the W3.CSS code is that your overrides have to follow any external spreadsheets already in the document. In other words, your "head" has to look like this with your internal stylesheet following AFTER the external stylesheets:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Aux02 - Landing Page</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3-theme-black.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
.local-display-bottommiddle {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
</style>
</head>
```

By the way, as you can probably guess from my selectors, I slightly renamed the local variants of the W3.CSS classes to make it apparent they were in an internal stylesheet but you could have left the class names unchanged and your local overrides should still have taken precedence over the code in the external stylesheets.

I'm just new to W3.CSS too so if I've gotten this wrong, I hope someone with more expertise will correct me!